# Ruby on Rails "Where" method Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Am so confused here. My Events model has many schedules. In my schedules model I have date and county attributes. Schedule model belongs to an Event.

I am filtering by a param[county_id:] In my controller.

I want to find all Events that have a county_id of 0 let's say.

The association is Event.schedules.county
I have got this to work for similar params search for Category

Event belongs_to :category
Category has_many :events

```
    if params[:category].present?
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:county].present?
        @schedules = Schedule.find_by(county: params[:county])
    else
        @events = Event.where(status: 1).order("created_at DESC")
    end
```

As you can see here. I can grab a group of schedules and can see and event_id attached to each. How can I make it that my front end can just stay looping through @events variable instead of looping through @schedules variable and having to go schedule.event.title etc

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is what `joins` is for. You can read about it in the Active Record Query Interface Guide [Section 12 Joining Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). BTW, it's not a Postgres thing, it's an AR thing.

Comment: joins. lovely. Thought as much. They make my head spin. Thanks @jvillian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below. Thanks to @jvillian for pointing me in the right direction.

```
    # simple filter for category select on idex page    
elsif params[:category].present?
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
elsif params[:county].present?
    @events = Event.joins(:schedules).where(schedules: {county: params[:county]}).all
else
    @events = Event.where(status: 1).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: Glad to be of some help. BTW, I don't believe you really need the `all` at the end. The query will be triggered when you access @events. But, that's a nit.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah avoided joins since sql days. Made my head spin. The active record helper definitely helps get the head around it a lot easier. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. You owe me a pint.